# jump in the sign of loglikelihood

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I am trying to find the maximum of a loglikelihood function in a two dimensional parameter space__ e.g.  X,Y positions are the free parameters__  by making grids in the parameter space and compute the loglikelihood value in each point in the grid. My loglikelihood is defined as following:

```
logProb = sum (-.5*(data-model)/sigma)**2  - log(sqrt(2*pi)) - log(sigma)
```

**My question** is:
I see a jump in the loglikelihood values when I plot them in the two dimensional frame from negative values to the positive values. I don't now whether I have made a mistake when I have defined either my model or the likelihood, because **it is not statistically correct** if something like this happens or there is no problem with it?

I have to mentioned the test has been done on the simulated data and the peak of loglikelihood describes the input value of simulation with high precision.

[image]

Comment: The scales on the image is difficult to read. There is no reason there should be an error there. loglikelihood becomes zero if the likelihood comes from a density function which is exactly 1. That is possible, a highly peaked density can have density values larger than one, so positive loglikelihood. Then, parameter values giving worse fit, with not a so higly peaked function , will give negative loglikelihood. No surprise in there.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I posted an image with better quality. So you reckon there is no statistically conflict if there is a discontinuity in the loglikelihood values?

Comment: It is unclear from your explanation whether there is a discontinuity - a function can pass zero without discontinuity.

Comment: Where is this "jump" whereof you speak? (Note that the sign of a log likelihood is a meaningless threshold.) Regardless, this does not look remotely like a correctly computed log likelihood surface: even when the *data* are simulated, the log likelihood (which is a function only of the two parameters because the *data remain fixed for its calculation*) is going to be locally smooth almost everywhere; it's not going to have the salt-and-pepper outliers shown here. How exactly are you calculating the values shown in this image?

Comment: @whuber The jump happened between `-133.45` and `4085.73` loglikelihood values. About non-smooth structures in the likelihood, I was wondering the same but then I thought it might be due to the non-uniform value of errors *(sigma)* that cause the **salt-and-pepper outliers** as you have named them.

Comment: Let me repeat: there is something so strange about this plot that it simply cannot be what you claim. When you *fix* your dataset and plot its log likelihood, there will not be "outliers". You're not even generating new data to produce "outliers"; you're merely performing an arithmetical calculation.

Comment: To find out what is going on you should post your code!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it is very complicated likelihhood with a lot of parameters and to be honest I don't know from where I should start debugging it.

Comment: But is there any reason for the discontinuities we can se in that plot?  Can you see from the expression for the loglikelihood function that it must be continuous?  I would start the debugging by programming it from fresh again, without looking at the old code, using sound programming principles.